# Rename the file after being upload to folder

Tags: php

I have successfully uploaded my image to a folder and rename to serial number (eg:12345.jpg).

It is possible to rename the file after being upload to folder??

I am getting:

Warning: rename(/ABT1/uploads/Bicycle/test.jpg,/ABT1/uploads/Bicycle/test2.jpg): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3) in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\bicycleTheft\ABT1\test2.php on line 4

I have tried:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-update']))
{
    rename("/uploads/Bicycle/test.jpg", "/uploads/Bicycle/test2.jpg");

}
```

Comment: yes it is possible.

Comment: how?? i am getting-                                                                                       Warning: rename(/ABT1/uploads/Bicycle/test.jpg,/ABT1/uploads/Bicycle/test2.jpg): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3) in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\bicycleTheft\ABT1\test2.php on line 4

Comment: yes... solved. Thank you

Comment: the issue was: /uploads/Bicycle/test.jpg (Old file route) i just change to uploads/Bicycle/test.jpg (New file route, and it works)

Answer (score 0):

I just change to

```
rename("uploads/Bicycle/test2.jpg", "uploads/Bicycle/test5.jpg");
```